# Asp.Net - Size to content for table

Tags: asp.net, html-table

How can I make a table auto size to content (e.g. use the minimum size sufficient to show inner controls) in ASP.NET 3.5?

I have a table that has a couple of rows. Some rows are not always required to be shown (e.g. when all the controls in that row are hidden). I want those rows to be hidden (or size = 0) and consequently the table to become smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing your exact setup, it's hard to give a specific answer to fit your need. If a table row is displayed on the page, it will take up at least one line unless you turn it off. One method would be to set the table row to runat="server", and then set visible="false" in your code-behind if the controls within are not displaying.

```
<tr id="tr" runat="server">
<td>Controls</td>
</tr>
```

In your code-behind:

```
if( ControlsNotShowing )
    tr.Visible = false;
```

Comment: I hope there is an easier way of doing this, without me checking the control visibilities manually. This is a regular asp.net web project (one of the project templates of VS).

Comment: @ace I'm sure you could put together a recursive function to check visibility of the controls within a table cell or row, there's examples on SO that do that. Otherwise, you may have to look at a client side option.

Comment: Yes, a recursive function would work. By "manually", I meant the need to write code for checking the visibilities. Anyway, I am from the "desktop app" world (winforms, wpf), so was looking for something like TableLayoutPanel, which doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: Just as a comment, tables aren't the best way to lay out things on the web.  If you are just displaying columnar data, they're fine.  In the web world, you should use CSS to control layout and styling.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to provide more detail, but I'll take a stab at it.

Table automatically size to their content if you do not specify a width attribute of the table and td cells. So that is the easy part.

The question about showing or hiding rows is probably needs more detail.  If you are trying to show/hide from code behind/server side, you can make the row a server control and set its Visible property:

```
<tr runat="server" id="row1">
 <td>Hi</td>
</tr>
```

And then in code behind, set the Visible property

```
row1.Visible = false
```

If you want to hide the row on the client side, you can use javascript.  I'll leave that to you or another question, but, if you do hide a row using javascript, the table will automatically resize itself if the row that was removed had the widest content.